# Time complexity of determining whether a tree is a univalue tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Recently, I came across this question on binary trees:

> 1. Given some arbitrary non-balanced tree, whats the big-O to determine if it is uni-value  (all elements are same value).
> 2. Which would cause the worst big-O complexity in above case, a balanced
>    tree or a linear tree?

This is my answer to the question:

1. To determine if a tree is univalue, we will have to check each node. So, complexity is O(n).
2. Whether it is a linear tree or a balanced tree if they have the same number of nodes, there will be same number of comparisons. So, complexity will be same.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct. The complexity is linear in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you are given an arbitrary binary tree, in the worst case you have to inspect all the nodes to determine whether they have the same value. There's a simple adversarial argument you can use here - if your algorithm doesn't look at all values, since there's no relation between any distinct values in the tree, an adversary could feed you a tree where n - 1 values are all the same. If you didn't then look at the last value, the adversary could force your algorithm to be wrong by setting that value to the opposite of what your algorithm says.

On the other hand, if you're talking about a binary ***search*** tree, then you can solve this in time O(h), where h is the height of the tree. Specifically, just look at the first and last values and see if they're the same. If so, all intermediary values in the tree must be the same. If they aren't, then you've witnessed two distinct values. This will run in time O(log n) on a perfectly balanced tree and O(n) on a degenerate linked list. I suspect this might have been what the original question was asking, since it's a more interesting question than the general binary tree case (at least, in my opinion).

Hope this helps!